# How to change the size of the specified text font through the getpointsize function

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQBZ.png)
This is the code of the function in the graphics library. I want to zoom the text box through the button, but the size of the menu does not change. How can I achieve this? This is the graphics library of ZJU.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And, please, don't provide the code with an image. Use the `code` option throughout the buttons that StackOverflow provides to you while you edit your question. Also, provide the minimum necessary code for which we can reproduce your problem.